# Does this question belong on English or Writers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Before a commenter mentioned it, I was unaware that there was a Writers site.  Is https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49380/techniques-to-disguise-authorship-of-text better suited to English or Writers?

**Edit:**

The linked question was moved to Writers, thereby answering my previous question.  Why was the question determined to be better suited to Writers?

(This question is not intended in any way to dispute the decision to migrate the question.  Instead, the intent is to document for the community *why* the question fell on the Writers side of the line rather than the English side.)

Comment: Well, I think you've got your answer ;-)

Comment: @MattЭллен Agreed.  But, it's probably good to have the actual reasoning on the record for anyone who might care to read it, so I'll edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It belongs on Writers because it's asking about how to write in a particular style. There's nothing in the question that is unique to the English language; it just so happens that you are writing in English, but your question is about the writing process and not the English language. If you were writing in, say, French instead, the answer would be the exact same; there's nothing about this question that is particular to English.

Comment: That makes sense.  I guess I do not know whether the language would affect the answer, but the question could be asked about any language, as you say.  Thank you!